# I need some assistance in adding this unknown column in the most seamless way possible, how can I do this?

Tags: php

So I am using the Laravel 5.x framework and I have built a photo gallery application. After I created and migrated the tables via php artisan I later added 'location' in my code and it has since thrown everything off like so:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'location' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `photos` (`title`, `description`, `location`, `gallery_id`, `image`, `owner_id`) values (, This is a description of the website logo, Philadelphia, 1, screenshot.png, 1))
```

Here is the PhotoController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class PhotoController extends Controller
{
    private $table = 'photos';

    // Show Create Form
    public function create($gallery_id){
        // Render View
        return view('photo/create', compact('gallery_id'));
    }

    // Store Photo
    public function store(Request $request){
        // Request input
        $gallery_id = $request->input('gallery_id'); 
        $title = $request->input('name');
        $description = $request->input('description');
        $location = $request->input('location'); 
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $owner_id = 1;

        // Check Image upload
        if($image){
            $image_filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path('images'), $image_filename);
        } else {
            $image_filename = 'noimage.png';
        }

        // Insert Photo
        DB::table($this->table)->insert(
            [
                'title'        => $title,
                'description' => $description,
                'location'    => $location,
                'gallery_id'  => $gallery_id,
                'image'       =>$image_filename,
                'owner_id'    => $owner_id
            ]
        );

        // Set Message
        \Session::flash('message', 'Photo added');

        // Redirect
        return \Redirect::route('gallery.show' , array('id' => $gallery_id));
    } 

    // Show Photo Details
    public function details($id){
        die($id);
    }
}
```

this is my create_photos_table.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePhotosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('cover_image');
            $table->integer('owner_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('photos');
    }
}
```

This is my layouts/create.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
     <div class="callout primary">
            <div class="row column">
              <h1>Upload Photo</h1>
              <p class="lead">Upload a photo to the gallery</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-4">
            <div class="main">
                {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'PhotoController@store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}
                        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('title', $value = null, $attributes = ['placeholder' => 'Photo Title', 'name' => 'title ']) !!}

                        {!! Form::label('description', 'Description') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('description', $value = null, $attributes = ['placeholder' => 'Photo Description', 'name' => 'description']) !!}

                {!! Form::label('description', 'Location') !!}
                {!! Form::text('location', $value = null, $attributes = ['placeholder' => 'Photo Location', 'name' => 'location']) !!}

                        {!! Form::label('image', 'Photo') !!}
                        {!! Form::file('image') !!}

                <input type="hidden" name="gallery_id" value="{{$gallery_id}}">

                        {!! Form::submit('Submit', $attributes = ['class' => 'button']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
          </div>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to add a new table field, is to create new migration for upgrading a current existing table. For example, you create a new migration with the name `add_location_to_photos` (`php artisan make:migration add_location_to_photos`). Then you open the migration file and add the new field inside like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('location')->after('description');
    }
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('location');
    });
}
```

Then you run the migration by `php artisan migrate` and you have the `photos` table upgraded with the new field `location`. You would have to add that field to the `photos` Model, but I can see you don't use a Model for the `photos` table, so, you just use the field in your direct DB queries.

You can also hard-code it and edit the table directly using a DB editor, create the new `location` field and change the initial migration file to have that field inside it, but that's not the proper way although it works fine in any case.

Comment: thanks, this worked except for now I have this error: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php which I believe means that now a token is required in the form, no?

Comment: Actually, I am actually still getting the same error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `photos` (`title`, `description`, `location`, `gallery_id`, `image`, `owner_id`) values (, This is a description of the website logo, Philadelphia, 1, screenshot.png, 1))

Comment: @Daniel you should do the same for the image field. You don't get the `location` field related error any more, do you? You could have added the image field to the same migration file, but if you've done the migration, then you should create a new one and add the image field there. `TokenMismatchException` has nothing to do with this one, but I can check on it and tell you which form methods you have to use in order to have a valid Csrf Token.